# Terminal in Mac OS X Yosemite gets messed up after exiting vim

Tags: terminal, macos

This happens with either stock Yosemite terminal, or iterm2.  When I exit vim, this is my terminal.  As you can see, colors are messed up in my terminal after exiting vim and it doesn't come back until I terminate terminal app (not a pun :P).

[image]

I have to add that I'm a bit new to vim (a couple of months) and reaaaaaally new to Mac OS (less than a month).  The same vimrc works well in Linux.

Comment: Does this also happen in you start Vim with no vimrc file (`vim -u NONE`)?

Comment: Nope... so this is an issue in my vimrc, right?

Comment: Looks like it :-) try: [How do I debug my vimrc file?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51) and post the settings that cause this behaviour.

Comment: it seems that was a bug in the version i had in vim-airline.  I followed the posts instructions on how to debug my vimrc, i commented out the plugins and everything worked ok.  So i started commenting out one by one each plugin, and when i did so in vim-airline it bugged again.  So i found out how to update my plugins (vim +PluginUpdate) and now everything works ok.  Thnx @Carpetsmoker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that was a bug in the version of `vim-airline` I had.  Following the posts instructions on how to debug my `vimrc`, I commented out the plugins and everything worked ok.  So I started commenting out one by one each plugin, and when i did so in `vim-airline` it bugged again.  So i found out how to update my plugins (i use Vundle as a plugin manager, so

```
vim +PluginUpdate
```

or

```
:PluginUpdate
```

from inside vim as @Edward reminded me) and now everything works ok.  Thnx @Carpetsmoker and @Edward.

So, just a reminder, plugins can have bugs as well, so investigate when in doubt.

Comment: It sounds like you're using vundle as your plugin manager. If so, you can also update your plugins from within an existing vim session with the `:PluginUpdate` command.

Comment: this is true, i will update my answer regarding this.

Comment: I never would have figured this out in a million years. Thank you!